# Troubles doing 'const customerSaved = await newCustomer.save()'

Tags: mongodb, authentication, next.js, schema, stripes

I´m having problems when I try to save information of two different schemas in the same petion.

Context: the project it is in next.js and I'm using mongodb as database provider.

It throws this error:

> Algo a ido mal User validation failed: password: The password is required, email: E-mail is required, lastname: Path `lastname` is required., firstname: Path `firstname` is required.

PostData: The `user.save()` works correctly.

```js
export default async function register(request, response) {
    await connectDB();
    const { Firstname, Lastname, Email, Password } = request.body;
    const stripe = Stripe(process.env.SK_PRIVATE);
    console.log(Firstname, Lastname, Email, Password);

    try {
        //Registro de Usuario de la pagina en la base de datos
        const UserFound = await User.findOne({ Email });
        if (UserFound)
            return response
                .status(400)
                .json({ message: "El email ya ha sido registrado" });
        if (!Password || Password.length < 7)
            return response
                .status(400)
                .json({ message: "At least needs 7 characters" });
        const hash = await bcrypt.hash(Password, 10);

        const newUser = new User({
            firstname: Firstname,
            lastname: Lastname,
            email: Email,
            password: hash,
        });

        const userSaved = await newUser.save();

        console.log("hecho");
        //Registro de Customer user data en la base de datos
        const customer = await stripe.customers.create({
            name: Firstname,
            email: Email,
        });

        const newCustomer = new Customer({
            userId: userSaved._id,
            stripeCustomerId: customer.id,
        });

        const customerSaved = await newCustomer.save();

        console.log("Cliente guardado con éxito:", customerSaved);

        response.json({
            message: "Se ha registrado correctamente",
        });
        console.log("Datos recibidos en el servidor:", hash, Email);
    } catch (error) {
        response.status(500).json({ message: error.message });
        console.log("Algo a ido mal", error.message);
    }
}
```